# JAXB binding nested elements

Tags: java, jaxb

I am using JAXB-impl. I need to be able to map nested elements to class fields as simple types. For example:

```
<mapping>

    <search>
        <channel>main-channel</channel>
        <url>my-channel-url</url>
    </search>

    <items>
        <item>first</item>
        <item>second</item>
        <item>third</item>
    </items>

</mapping>
```

Assuming I need to bind "url" tag to a field in the class, this will not work (of course):

```
class Mapping{

    @XmlElement
    private String url;
}
```

@XmlElementWrapper, is for collections only. I have seen some post about using eclipse MOXy, and utilize @XmlPath, but this is not an option. It has to be JAXB-impl.

for reference:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/XPath#Marshal_to_XML_-_MOXy_Customization_.231_-_Grouping_Element

Is there a way to get this mapping without having to create these extra nested classes ?

Comment: Why not create the nested classes?

Comment: This could be an option. However, accessing the fields like:

mapping.getUrl();

is cleaner than:

mapping.getNestedClass.getUrl();

I am not sure if it makes sense to create the nested class, just to satisfy JAXB. I prefer not to create the nested class, but I may end up having to create it.

Comment: Do you need to read and write the XML or just read?

Comment: Just read. No write needed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With additional class `Search`, but this class is private nested class, and not used outside of `Mapping` class.
public API of class `Mapping` returns url as expected

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Mapping
{
   @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
   private static class Search
   {
      private String channel;
      private String url;
   }

   private Search search;

   public String getUrl()
   {
      return search == null ? null : search.url;
   }
}
```