# JAXB binding 3 level nested elements

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I am trying to bind the following xml to java using jaxb

```
<Validation> 
...
        <Options>
             <AllowUnspecifiedParameters>
                  <Header> True </Header>
                  <Query> True </Query>
                  <Cookies> True </Cookies>
             </AllowUnspecifiedParameters>
        </Options>
</Validation>
```

I have seen some similar example like [JAXB binding nested elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640899/jaxb-binding-nested-elements)
But the deepest nested level is for list, @XmlElementWrapper is for collections only, so it looks like not fitting my case.

Anyone know how I can do it? Really appreciate it.

Comment: You may use DSM library if your XML is complex. mfatihercik.github.io/dsm

Comment: @mfe thanks for suggestion. but I am working on an old codebase so my choice is limited

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1** One pure JaxB way to do this is via defining your adapter for Options element. The adapter is used to more or less turn any xml into any object and vice versa (Custom marshaling).

```
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(OptionsAdapter.class)

    public class OptionsAdapter extends extends XmlAdapter<Element, Options> {

    @Override
        public Element marshal(Options v) throws Exception {
            // put your marshaling logic here
        }

        @Override
        public Options unmarshal(Element node) throws Exception {
           // put your unmarshaling logic here
        }

    }

Then in the class holding the options element you will have:

    public class ClazzHoldingOptions {

      @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(OptionsAdapter.class)
      private Options options;

    }
```

**Option 2** EclipseLink has the feature of mapping elements via xpath expressions

```
     @XmlPath("AllowUnspecifiedParameters/Header/text()")
     private String  header;

https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.4/org/eclipse/persistence/oxm/annotations/XmlPath.html
```

**Option 3** While reading the code of @df778899 I think that his solution is not optimal, but it addresses a problem I have not addressed so far. And it is when you have so many attributes that you actually don't want to map them, or if you simply don't have control over the XML content and don't trust it and don't want breaking changes. In which I would just map to a HashMap:

```
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(OptionsAdapter.class)

    public class OptionsAdapter extends extends XmlAdapter<Element, Options> {

    @Override
        public Element marshal(Hashmap v) throws Exception {
            // put your marshaling logic here
        }

        @Override
        public HashMap unmarshal(Element node) throws Exception {
           // put your unmarshaling logic here
        }

    }

Then in the class holding the options element you will have:

    public class ClazzHoldingOptions {

      @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(OptionsAdapter.class)
      private HashMap options;

    }
```

Summary. So let me summarise the pros and cons

**Option 1.**   +Standard Aproach pure jaxB
            +Good if you have control own the schema of the xml file. Or if the schema is not expected to change every month.
            -Bad if the schema or the xml file is very volatile.

**Option 2.**   +Extremly easy to use. No need for adapters.
            -Again not optimal solution if your schema is volatile.
            -Requires specific JaxB implementation

**Option 3.**   -Only good if you have a volatile xml for avoiding breaking changes.

PS: The only case when I would use something like @df778899 solution is if there is extreme structural uncertainty of what will come in the XML.  For example if I know that something will come in the xml but I dont know where exactly. PLus it is memory inneficient, do you want to hold all the metadata related to your xml in memory.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! In terms of option1, I am not quite sure what is your `Element` type?

Comment: @yusong org.w3c.dom.Element

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `@XmlAnyElement` to provide the nested elements, though they come back in fairly raw form - as `org.w3c.dom.Element` instances:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Validation")
public class Validation {
    private List<Element> options;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Options")
    @XmlAnyElement
    public List<Element> getOptions() {
        return options;
    }

    ...
}
```

The data can then be drilled down into:

```
    Validation validation = (Validation) unmarshaller.unmarshal(source);
    for (Element element : validation.getOptions()) {
        System.out.println(element.getNodeName() + ":");
        NodeList childNodes = element.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Node childNode = childNodes.item(i);
            if (childNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                System.out.println("  " + childNode.getNodeName() + "=" +
                        childNode.getTextContent());
        }
    }
```

Which shows all the data coming through:

```
AllowUnspecifiedParameters:
  Header= True 
  Query= True 
  Cookies= True
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my question above has a simple answer :

XML :

```xml
<Validation> 
...
        <Options>
             <AllowUnspecifiedParameters>
                  <Header> True </Header>
                  <Query> True </Query>
                  <Cookies> True </Cookies>
             </AllowUnspecifiedParameters>
        </Options>
</Validation>
```

Java Object :

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "Validation")
public class Validation {

  // some more fields
  // ...


  private Options option = new Options();

  @XmlElement(name = "Options")
  public Options getOptions() {
    return options;
  }

}

public class Options {

  @XmlElement(name = "AllowUnspecifiedParameters")
  public StrictOptions allowUnspecifiedParameters = new StrictOptions();

  public static class StrictOptions {
    @XmlElement(name = "Header")
    public boolean header = true;

    @XmlElement(name = "Query")
    public boolean query = true;

    @XmlElement(name = "Cookie")
    public boolean cookie = true;

  }
}
```

But if you have a really complicated xml schema or java object structure, as @df778899 and @Alexandar Petrov suggested,  `XmlAdapter` and `@ XmlAnyElement` are powerful tools.

Here is one example I found : [Mapping an Arbitrary List of Objects Using JAXB's @XmlAnyElement and XmlAdapter](https://dzone.com/articles/mapping-arbitrary-list-objects)